# Collecting signals from 128 sensors with Arduino

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer

I am using eight 74HC4067 (which are 1x16-Channel Analog multiplexer/demultiplexers) to collect data from 128 sensors. Now that translates to 8 data pins on the Arduino which I don't have.
Is there a way to decode the multiplexers data to just one single input?

Comment: _"Is there a way to decode the multiplexers data to just one single input?"_ How many GPIO pins and/or which communication peripherals are available?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 8 data pins. If you mean you need 8 ADC pins, you can do the same with that multiplexer. Add another multiplexer and use only the first 8 channels to mux those 8 pins to 1 ADC pin. To select the proper sensor, you will need to set both multiplexers to the appropriate channel.

Comment: Muliplex the multiplexers.

Comment: Or use a i2c gpio chip.